# Flipping line based on distance with another feature class using ModelBuilder or Python Script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have two feature classes Line and point.

I need to change the flow direction based on a distance with a point feature class.

If the start vertices is far from the point, the system should flip the line.

I want the starting for all line features to be near the point feature class.

Shall I use ModelBuilder or a Python script?

Comment: What version and license level of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? You will need ArcEditor/Standard or higher if you want to use the [**Flip Lines tool**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000005000000.htm) in a model.  I would use a Python script tool unless you have a strong preference to use ModelBuilder.

Comment: (Advanced) ArcInfo

Comment: Actually I can use python script if available

Comment: So you want to flip the direction of a polyline if the distance of it's starting vertex exceeds a value (set by you) to a point in a point FeatureClass? Presumably this point FeatureClass has many points in it, so which point (in the point FeatureClass) are you attempting to compute a distance from: nearest, some or all of them?

Comment: Actually, it depends on the nearest point. can I select a point and run the script. if i can't, i will try to find a solution because I only have 5 points. I want the script to calculate the distance between the point and start point and end point of the line. and if the distance between Point feature and end point is less than the distance between point feature class and start point. the line must flip. I want the start point of line to be near the specified point.

Answer (score 1):

You could knock all this logic together in a model or write it as python. As you have ArcInfo this makes life easier.  This is one way to do it:

1. Use the Feature Vertices To Points tool and extract END point of your polylines.
2. Run the Near tool which creates the field NEAR_DIST.
3. Add a field called "flip" to the output of the near tool and initially set to zero.
4. Select the distances (in field NEAR_DIST) which are less than your specified distance and set all the rows in flip to 1.
5. You can join this table back to your polyline layer.
6. With the joined table select all polylines where flip = 1.
7. Then run the flip lines tool as mentioned by PolyGeo.
8. Break the join

You could limit which points are tested by imposing an initial selection based on some criteria. Creating a flip field has the added advantage of recording which polylines you had flipped.